# matplotlib - how to plot bar graphs side-by-side to compare values between 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a data set of certain values, separated by 2008 and 2013. However, when I plot them out using matplotlib, only the values in 2008 appear in the bar graph.

I would like to have bargraph of 2008 and 2013 side-by-side for comparison.

[image: Image of the data]

So far I only managed to produce this
[image: Values of 2008, separated by flat_type]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.genfromtxt('C:\data/IT8701_CA2_Data/hdb-resident-population-by-flat-type.csv', 
                        skip_header=1, 
                        dtype=[('shs_year','U50'),('flat_type','U50'),('resident_population','i8')], delimiter=",",
                        missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])`
labels = list(set(data['flat_type']))
labels.sort()
residents = np.arange(0,len(labels))
residents_values = data[['flat_type','resident_population']]

values = residents_values['resident_population']

units_values = {}

for i in labels:
valuesforFY = values[residents_values['flat_type']==i] 
print("No.of Residents in Flat_type: " + i + " is {}".format(valuesforFY))
#the line below is critical
units_values[i] = valuesforFY

plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8))
xdata =  list(units_values.keys())
ydata = [i[0] for i in units_values.values()]
barchart = plt.bar(xdata, ydata, color='b')
```

Comment: Check out [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) in particular https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses pandas, but should give you what you need if you want to change your data structure.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2008', '2008', '2013', '2013'],['a','b','a','b'], [3,7,5,6]]).T
df.columns = ['year', 'type', 'value']
df.set_index(['year', 'type'], inplace=True)

df.unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use groupy. Something like:

```
for group in df.groupby('year'):
   group.plot(...)
```